# LINQ To SQL C# Update With Class

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have `users` table with generated LINQ-class with followed structure:

```
class User {
    int Id;
    string Login;
    string Password;
    string Mail;
    ...
```

Now I need to update specified columns (for ex. only Login and Password) and because I don't want to overwrite other fields, my code looks like this:

```
public User UpdateUser(int userId, User newUser)
{
    User user = (from u in _context.Users
                where u.Id == userId
                select u).FirstOrDefault();

    if (newUser.Login != default(string)) user.Login = newUser.Login;
    if (newUser.Mail != default(string)) user.Mail = newUser.Mail;
    if (newUser.Password != default(string)) user.Password = newUser.Password;
    ...

    _context.SubmitChanges();
    return user;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var user = new User { Password = "123" };
UpdateUser(123, user);
```

For each field I need to write IF statement and I thinking that I doing something wrong. Also because I am using comparsion with `default(string)` I cannot set empty values to rows.
Please, tell me, what is right way to do this?

P.S.: Please, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Pretty risky storing free text passwords.

Comment: @ChaosPandion it's an abstract example, in production I use `Crypto.HashPassword`.

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing LINQ 2 SQL. You shouldn't even have a generic `UpdateUser` method because you don't need it. If you want to write a certain field of an entity, just do it:

```
var user = GetUser(userId);
user.Password = "123";
```

And you're done. When you have made all changes to the object model, call `SubmitChanges` at the end. It is not necessary to call it after each mutation.

You are using LINQ 2 SQL as a CRUD repository but it is not meant to be one. It is meant to give you a live object model that you can treat like normal C# objects. In the end you synchronize with the database by calling `SubmitChanges`.

Comment: OK, I understand. Can you give me a link where I can read a tutorial for proper LINQ To SQL usage, please?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-linq-to-sql-part-1 Scott Guthrie always shows off technologies like they are meant to be used. Look how simple everything looks in that post. That's because it is.

Comment: According to this tutorial, I need to write queries in controller, but I am thinking that right way is create DAL classes and call its methods. That's why I create CRUD repositories with functions like in first post. What I need to return to controller instead classes with data?

Comment: The tutorial does not say at all that you have to query in the controller. You can put the code anywhere you like. If you want to have a DAL (which is not required) add semantic operations to it (like SetUserPassword(userId, password)). But not CRUD operations like UpdateUser.

Comment: The problem is that I want to update not only one field, I want to update dynamic number of fields. In this example it is only `Password` field, but if I need to change many fields at once (for example, `About`, `Website` and `City` fields), am I need to create method `UpdateAboutWebsiteCity(about, website, city)`? I think that `UpdateUser(123, new User { About = about, Website = website, City = city})` is better way, but I don't know how to realize it.

Comment: If the DAL only hinders you and gives you nothing then don't have a DAL! Just write fields in the controller. Nothing wrong with that. Anyway, if you insist on copying object properties around, look into AutoMapper or ask a new question that is not LINQ specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible just with SubmitChanges:

```
This gets the user:
    var user=context.User.Where(m=>m.id == "xyz").FirstOrDefault();

This updates the above user:
user.Password = "xyz";
context.User.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking into the wrong way for optimization. An `update` command on single column isn't much different than on every other column than PK. Your validation logics might take more time to process than your optimized `update` command.

However if it is always the password that needs to be updated, you can do it this way :

```
public User ChangePassword(int userId, string password)
{
  var user = new User() { Id = userId };
  _context.Users.Attach(user); 
  user.Password = password;
  _context.SaveChanges();

  return user;
}
```

Comment: This does not work well in the bigger picture because you can't call this method twice because you can't attach twice. In fact even the first call might fail if the entity happens to be loaded already.

Comment: Just to drive home the point: This is against how L2S is meant to be used. You are using it as a CRUD repository which it is not.